# How to create simple sticky lips

Tags: modeling, sculpting, sculpt-mode

I want to create cartoonish lips for my character. I used several methods but still can't figure it out, is there any way to create sticky lips like this from scratch or sculpting. here is an image for more details. but it must be on a sphere
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "but it must be on a sphere"?

Comment: I mean this lips on a cube but I want that in a sphere
But if you use sculpting then no need of it

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cube, subdivide, cut a hole:

[image]

Extrude the edge loop of the hole and scale down:

[image]

Add loopcuts, move some vertices, extrude the lips inwards:

[image]

It will be exactly the same thing with a sphere: First cut a hole:

[image]

Then extrude and scale down:

[image]

Move some vertices, add loop cuts, extrude inwards:

[image]

If you want to make sure that it keeps a good spherical shape, you can use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier with a sphere as target.

Comment: is this method also work with the UV sphere

Comment: Sure, please show or share your wireframe

Comment: It just a simple UV sphere
https://ibb.co/pxRTJzr

Comment: So, same thing, you just need to cut a hole, extrude and scale down, add some loopcuts, etc